# How to retrieve cookie on the client side sent by c# server Response.Cookies.Append method

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

Can I retrieve on the angular client side cookie sent by the c# server like in the code below (and how to do that if possible).

```
private void setTokenCookie(string token)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
    };
    Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
}
```

Comment: HttpOnly cookies cannot be seen by client side Javascript. Set HttpOnly to false and you will be able to read it from Javascript.

Comment: I did and I still can't see it when I do `const cookie = document.cookie;` - `cookie` is an empty string. Is that cookie send back to the server with the next request from the client?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to attempt to answer my own question after two days of experiments and investigation.

Sending cookie to c# server and back from c# server to angular client is a few steps process:

First send a message (post/get etc) from client to server - with the `withCredentials: true`:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/authenticate`, { email, password }, { withCredentials: true } )
            .pipe(map(account => {
                const body = account.body;
                this.accountSubject.next(account.body);
                const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 7*24*60*60*1000).toUTCString();

                const cookie = document.cookie; <-- for debugging purpose only
                //document.cookie = `refreshToken=${body.refreshToken}; expires=${expires}; path=/`;
                this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
                return account;
            }));
}
```

Then send from c# server back to the client the cookie added to the Response object like below (this sets the cookie on the client side):

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = false, // false for debug purpose to be able to see it on the client side
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
};
Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
```

After that the cookie is send by the angular client automatically to the c# server every time we execute another post/get etc command

Can some expert please confirm that this is what is happening with cookies handling between server and client?